# Angular2 routing config without component

Tags: angular, routes, guard

I have a route that is openend when the user clicks a link in an email. That link contains some tokens and IDs which need to be inspected. Depending on the outcome of the inspection I would redirect the user to the respective routes. For example, the user could be routed to an error page, to a register/logon page or directly to his dashboard.

Furthermore, I don't want to do the inspection in the component, because I don't want any template to be rendered during the checks. The first page the user should see is the one he finally gets routed to. So, I do the checks in a `guard`.

Nevertheless I need to configure a component in the route config, which eventually will never be rendered. Of course, I could define an arbitrary component there, but actually the `guard` alone would be sufficient here.

I admit, this is more an esthetic thing but a real problem :) On the other hand, there could be a more straight-forward approach, I don't know about. Any ideas/opinions on that?

Comment: I think there was an issue created to make the router more forgiving in such cases and ignore that there is not component configured until it is actually required. I don't know about progress of this issue. I just use a `DummyComponent` with an empty template.

Answer (score 2):

I found myself in the same situation as described in your question, yet, I disliked the idea to create a "DummyComponent" just to satisfy the router api.

Hence, I went with an empty children array:

```
path: '**',
canActivate: [RouteGuard],
children: []
```

Then your `RouteGuard` can take over and do the redirection magic dynamically basing it's routing decision on the current application state.

Comment: note: a routeguard can return a UrlTree which may be useful for redirects